# Get font color of ReactJS element

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a React component, a button, and I need to set the `background-color` of a child element to the `color` of the button.  I know that you're not supposed to call `this.refs.myElement.getDOMNode()` in the `render()` function, so I'm not sure how I'm supposed to lay this out.

At the moment, my code looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, Glyphicon } from 'react-bootstrap';
import classnames from 'classnames';

export default class GlyphButton extends Button {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        let {
            glyph,
            className,
            children,
            ...props
        } = this.props;

        return (
            <Button ref='btn' {...props} className={classnames([className, 'glyph-button'])}>
                <Glyphicon glyph={glyph} />
                {children}
            </Button>
        );
    }
}
```

I need to do something like this:

```
let color = this.refs.btn.style.color;
return (
    <Button ref='btn' ...>
        <Glyphicon glyph={glyph} style={{backgroundColor: color}} />
        {children}
    </Button>
);
```

Unfortunately, `this.refs` hasn't been populated yet.

In case you're curious, the reason I'm doing this is because I'm using Glyphicon's free version PNGs for some icons, which are all black on a transparent background, and I'm using:

```
glyphicon.glyphicon-playing-dice:before {
   content: "";
   width: 20px;
   height: 20px;
   -webkit-mask-size: 100%;
   -webkit-mask-image: url(/img/glyphicons/glyphicons-playing-dice.png);
   display: block;
}
```

to make it act like a font icon.  This class will make the element's `background-color` the color of the displayed icon.

Comment: Where does the button get its color from?

Comment: It's either specified in `style` or it gets it from its nearest ancestor that has it defined... by default, `body`'s `color` is black.

Comment: Keep in mind that `btn.style.color` will only give you the color if it was set inline. If the color is inherited you have to use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle. I suggest to pass the color as prop to the overall component and then you can set it as color of the button and background color of the image. If that's not possible, you have to wait until the component mounted (`componentDidMount`)\, get the style of the button and update the component's state with the color to trigger a rerender.

Comment: Yeah, that was supposed to be pseudo-code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `color` as a state and change it in `componentDidMount` stage.

```
getInitialState: function(){
   return {bgColor: ''}
 },
componentDidMount: function(){
   var color = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.btn).style.color;
    this.setState({bgColor : color});
}
```

Because React recommend us that :

> your first inclination is usually going to be to try to use refs to "make things happen" in your app. If this is the case, take a moment and think more critically about where state should be owned in the component hierarchy.